# Using Multiple Topic Config in on Producer Spring Reactive Kafka

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

I am new to Kafka and We are using Spring Web Flux in the application. We have a requirement to push two different messages to two different Topics say T1 and T2. Kafka Broker is the same.
We are using ***ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate*** and it working fine.

```
    @Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, Object> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate(
            KafkaProperties properties) {
        final Map<String, Object> props = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        return new ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, Object>(SenderOptions.create(props));
    }
```

Now we have requirement to compress only one Topic[T1] content alone as the message size is more on the Topic T1.
Do we have something like [RoutingKafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#routing-template) support in Reactive Kafka or Project Reactor where we can modify the Producer Config as per Topic needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; there is no equivalent; you need to configure two templates with different producer configs.

Comment: You mean to use something like the accepted answer in below thread right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57905042/can-we-use-multiple-kafka-template-in-spring-boot

Comment: Something similar; yes.